Ubuntu closes down apps and the toolbar and icons get a weird symbol
So Ive had this twice now but both times were when I walked away. I cannot remember what I was doing the first time but this time I was running a python code overnight. The code should have run for 8 hours but it only ran 2 hours by estimate of how many files are generated. When I got back and turned on my screens there was an error for firefox. The toolbar was gone from the sidebar. Visual studio had closed down and the power off button and some others were different symbols. Sort of a gray square with a white border.
I checked journalctl if anythin was closed by systemd-oomd but that did not happen. Anyone any clue what it could be?
Ubuntu version 22.04 LTS.
graphics NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 / NVIDIA Corporation
RAM 64 GB
disk space 1TB on the partition. there is another 1TB for windows. But the issue is on ubuntu.
Processor Intel® Core™ i7-14700K × 28.
